# unsupported match type for string: CONTAINS_ANY

Tags: karate

I want to validate value match of all items in string array

`response.data[0].attributes.status` where contains any `["active","deleted" ,"deleting","processing"]`

Comment: Try explaining your question with some examples. provide somewhat more details.

Comment: I want to validate value of "Status", this value could be active, deleted, deleting or processing, I tried use match contains any method but it's not work

Comment: Could you at least provide some code so we can see what you did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [karate documentation about the contains any matcher](https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains-any).

`contains any` expect that right and left side are of type json array or json object.

A simple example with json arrays:

```
 * match  ['active', 'deleted'] contains any ['status', 'active']
```

Same for json objects:

```
 * match  {'foo':'bar'} contains any {'foo':'bar', 'mr':'pink'}
```

**Your question:** 
You want to match that your status is one of  `["active","deleted" ,"deleting","processing"]`. Or in other words, `["active","deleted" ,"deleting","processing"]` contains status.

Karate speak:

```
 * match ["active","deleted" ,"deleting","processing"] contains response.data[0].attributes.status
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter, my test is passed

Comment: @cuhavp: Please, mark this answer as correct then, thanks!

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, but I don't understand that there is no easier option available for Karate.

Comment: @NLxDoDge What do you mean with easier. You have two additional words `match` and `contains` it's pretty short, isn't it?
Or do you want an expression to flip operants like `match response.data[0].attributes is one of ["X", "Y", "Z"]` for instance?

Comment: Yes that was my initial guess, but after reading the documentation I found out that was not possible. So I had no clue how to further progress on this, because I also though that is was not allowed the other way as your original answer as well.